# Session wrapper class. Set multi dimensional array

Tags: php

I have a wrapper class for my `$_SESSION` array because I like to work with objects and it sort of prevents me from getting lazy and calling the super global from places I should not.

It used to be ok to have a simple:

```
public function get($name);
public function set($name, $value);
public function exists($name);
......
```

but now I am implementing a shopping service and it has a shopping cart and when the user adds  an item to the cart it sets it like `$_SESSION['cart'][$productId]` which holds the quantity so as you can see my `get()` and `set()` break down.

I currently have this for my new get()

```
/*
 * @args: ...
 * @return: mixed
 */
public function get() {

    $keys = func_get_args();
    $value = $_SESSION[array_shift($keys)];

    foreach( $keys as $key ) {
        $value = $value[$key];
    }

    return $value;
}

// This is how I use it then
$quantity = $session->get('cart', $productId);
```

It works with perfectly assuming the keys being search for do exist, otherwise it gives me a warning.

The problem now is the set() method. I want to do it in a similar fashion so any amount of keys can be given in the signature of the method and then the value to store but it is proving to be very confusing for me anyway.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need the `foreach`-loop in the method? If you pass `'cart', $productId` then `$keys` will contain `$productId` after `array_shift`. Then you simply could do: `return ( isset($value[$keys[0]]) ? $value[$keys[0]] : null );`.

Comment: rather, why is your get method's definition not `public function get($key, $value)`

Comment: @insertusernamehere but I want this to be completely dynamic/flexible. I want to be able to call `$session->get('website', 'shopping', 'cart', 'items', $productId)` if they want. That is just an exaggerated example but you get the idea.

Comment: @kennypu is you are getting something what is the `$value` for?

Comment: Could you please post an answer on how to dynamically set a value any number of levels deep in the array with some code because it is hard to see what you mean in this little box.

Comment: you should really have a separate class called SessionCart and handle this requirement specifically than hacking it around

Comment: @DevZer0 it is not just for the session I want this because I will be using this wrapper for all my applications and I want it to be able to handle multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
class Session{
    // $...
    public function get(){
        $keys = func_get_args();

        if(count($keys) < 1){
            // handle exception
        }

        $value = $_SESSION[array_shift($keys)];

        foreach($keys as $key){
            if(!isset($value[$key])){
                // handle exception
            }

            $value = $value[$key];
        }

        return $value;
    }

    // $valueToSet, $...
    public function set(){
        $data = func_get_args();

        if(count($data) < 2){
            // handle exception
        }

        $val = array_shift($data);

        $value = &$_SESSION[array_shift($data)];

        foreach($data as $key){
            if(!isset($value[$key])){
                $value[$key] = array();
            }

            $value = &$value[$key];
        }

        $value = $val;
    }

    // $...
    public function exists(){
        $keys = func_get_args();

        if(count($keys) < 1){
            // handle exception
        }

        $tmp = array_shift($keys);

        if(!isset($_SESSION[$tmp])) return false;
        $value = $_SESSION[$tmp];

        foreach($keys as $key){
            if(!isset($value[$key])){
                return false;
            }

            $value = $value[$key];
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I can give you a little example:

```
$var = 'asdf';
$var_copy = $var;
$var_copy2 = &$var;

$var_copy = 'asdf2';
echo $var; // prints 'asdf'

$var_copy2 = 'asdf2';
echo $var; // prints 'asdf2'
```

And a little [link from php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)